# Next js jest worker causing high number of processes in cPanel

Tags: node.js, process, next.js, cpanel

MY nextjs app is causing high number of processes in my cPanel and it reached its limit over 1000 times in a single day.

Is this normal for a nextjs app since it renders on server? This is just an online shop and some APIs and has also an other app which is the admin dashboard of the shop.

It is not a large app but takes the number of process from 21 to 199 in my cPanel dashboard.

These are the last logs.

```
4072046  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072047  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072053  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072057  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072062  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072067  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072074  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072080  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072093  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072096  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072103  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072110  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072119  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072130  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072138  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072145  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072153  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072160  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072168  0.0   469M   Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072176  0.0   74M    Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072187  0.0   70M    Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
4072196  0.0   70M    Sl    04:59    00:00:00  \_         /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node  /home/mohaetwk/nodevenv/shahre-game/client/10/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the only issue was the limited number of processes on my cPanel hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `next build` fails to kill the `processChild` jest-worker sub-process.

Until Next.js fixes this issue:

1. Create a file, `terminate`,  in your local `~/bin` directory (make sure to add it to your `PATH`):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep "$@" | awk '{print $2}')
```

2. Make it executable: `chmod +x ~/bin/terminate`
3. Add `terminate processChild` to your build script/command:

```
next build && terminate processChild
```

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded to version nextJS 14, the problem was resolved. If we kill the sub-process, the code will not execute.